Preserving toolwindows' placements
When I open a new project, I want it to open with the settings of my previous project. It reverts to old settings every time. For example, I use the terminal on the right and when I open a new project, it moves to the bottom. I'm tired of this situation.
I want these tool windows to remain in the same place when I change their location and open a new project.

As seen in the image, I directed the terminal to the right side, but when I open a new project, the terminal moves to the bottom left again.

(I accidentally approved this question.) Duplicates: IntelliJ - How to use same tool window location for all projects?, How to save window position in Intellij Idea.

Yes, you can create a custom layout https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-window-layouts.html#create-a-custom-layout
